# Writing zip in terms of zipWith

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell through Chris Allen and Julie Moronuki's Haskell Programming book. Need help on one of the exercises for Zipping list. The exercise has 3 parts, first two are about writing our own implementation of zip and zipWith which i was able to.

```
myzip1 :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
myzip1 _ [] = []
myzip1 [] _ = []
myzip1 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : myzip1 xs ys

myZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
myZipWith _ _ [] = []
myZipWith _ [] _ = []
myZipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : myZipWith f xs ys
```

The last part asks to write zip in terms of zipWith. I am not able to come up with a solution. Honestly, i am not able to grasp the question completely (writing one function in terms of second, when function application of second is not required as it has all arguments first would require) .
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `zip = zipWith (,)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference between `myzip1` and `myZipWith` is

```
myzip1      (x:xs) (y:ys) =   (x,y) : myzip1      xs ys
myZipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : myZipWith f xs ys
```

Perhaps `myzip1` and `myZipWith f` are the same for some `f`.

```
myzip1 = myZipWith f
```

What would `f` be so that

```
(f x y) = (x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for elegant and thought provoking explanation.